# Echo value back on postback

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html

I have five  dropdown list which depending on the selection the display changes to block.
The problem comes when values are posted back. The drop down list does not show the values. This likely because of javascript that by default displays as none the drop down list. The javascript listens for onclick. Here is part of the javascripts:

```
 function changeOptions() {
    var form = window.document.getElementById("frm1");
    var sv = window.document.getElementById("sv");
    var sv2= window.document.getElementById("sv2");
var sv3 = window.document.getElementById("sv3");
    var sv4= window.document.getElementById("sv4");
var sv5 = window.document.getElementById("sv5");


if (form.radioButton1.checked) {
        sv2.style.display = "none";
sv3.style.display = "none";
sv4.style.display = "none";
sv5.style.display = "none";
        sv.style.display = "block";
        //sv.selectedIndex =0;

  else if (form.radioButton5.checked) {
        sv.style.display = "none";
        sv2.style.display = "none";
        sv3.style.display = "none";
        sv4.style.display = "none";
        sv5.style.display = "block";
        sv5.selectedIndex = 0;
    }

}
window.document.getElementById("radioButton5").onclick = changeOptions;
```

The dropdown menu is populated from my database. Below is the code. There are five of them The display:none changes to block depending which radio button is clicked.

```
   <select style="width:200px; **display:none**" name="pGroup" id="sv" >

<option value="Choose an Option" >Choose Product Group</option>
<?php
$selGroup = isset($_GET['pGroup'])?$_GET['pGroup']:"";
$sql="SELECT DISTINCT pGroup FROM cr39 WHERE ";
$sql.="HeadingNo = 3 ORDER BY pGroup ASC";
$result =mysql_query($sql);
while ($data=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
?>

<option <?php if($data['pGroup'] == $selGroup) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> value ="<?php echo $data['pGroup'] ?>" ><?php echo $data['pGroup'] ?></option>
<?php } ?>

</select>
```

.
.
.
.

```
    <select style="width:200px; **display:none**" name="pGroup5" id="sv5">

<option value="Choose an Option" >Choose Product Group</option>
<?php 
$selGroup = isset($_GET['pGroup5'])?$_GET['pGroup5']:"";
$sql="SELECT DISTINCT pGroup FROM cr39 WHERE ";
$sql.="HeadingNo = 7 ORDER BY pGroup ASC";
$result =mysql_query($sql);
while ($data=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
?>

<option <?php if($data['pGroup'] == $selGroup) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> value ="<?php echo $data['pGroup'] ?>" ><?php echo $data['pGroup'] ?></option>
<?php } ?>

</select>
```

I am a novice in this and would like help on how to retain the value on my dropdownon postback.

Comment: @mihai-iorga Get. Notice this line on code : $selGroup = isset($_GET['pGroup5'])?$_GET['pGroup5']:"";

Comment: I've noticed that, then what's with 'how to retain the value on my dropdownon postback.'? What do you mean postback? Please post full code

Comment: sounds like you are hiding sections until they are clicked with the radio button, and you want to reshow the last radio button selection and the associated sv# block, is that correct?  If so, you need to have PHP detect the _get/_post and output an `onload` javascript event to trigger the radio button selection with a `click()` so that the rest of your code fires and it shows the div

Comment: @Dave I understand what you mean. Its exactly whats happening. How do i het to that?

Comment: @mihai-iorga I mean if I had selected an item on my drop down. I want that value selected when my page is sent.

Comment: But that value is `$_GET['pGroup5']` ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

per comment above, would need to see more code to be exact, but here is a pseudo version that you may be able to adapt;

```
<body 
<?PHP if(isset($_GET['selectedGroupId'];)){ ?>
    onload='window.document.getElementById("radioButton<?PHP echo $_GET['selectedGroupId']; ?>").click()'
<?PHP } ?>
>
```

replace `$_GET['selectedGroupId']` with your fieldname/id

see if that gets you on the right track

Comment: My <select name=pGroup... have five different names. Which name then can I use?

Comment: change `onload` into a function, and list all the elements in the function...   `onload='setMySelection();'`  then in a javascript block somewhere  `function setMySelection(){ ` and several lines of your various blocks.    if I am misunderstanding your situation, post more raw code/html

Comment: what happens if you just `<body onload='changeOptions();' >`